# WSO2 API POST Python Web Service No Payload to server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Im using django restframework python in local its working fine as excepted (get,put,post,delete).Ran the server gave the endpoints in api manager and configured resources also,deployed.Get and delete method is working fine in wso2 apim ,but post and put method doesnt work.when i hit postman with required payload it goes to wso2 apim but in backend am getting null

i debugged at end backend (got to know payload becomes empty).i tried to find logs in wso2 apim

Comment: You can try enabling wire logs for the gateway. This will print the headers, request payload and response from the back end. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/configuring-logging/#gateway-wire-logs

Comment: when i enabled gateway wire logs and gave this code in log42 properities api manager isn't starting itself.loggers = synapse-wire, trace-messages, org-apache-coyote,com-hazelcast

Comment: any errors in the logs?

Comment: [2023-02-21 10:42:20,222] ERROR {TargetHandler} - HTTP protocol violation : Not a valid protocol version: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" For : 127.0.0.1:8000 org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Not a valid protocol version: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN".i used integration studio placed logger im able to see payload ,but whenever it goes to backend it becomes empty.